# JavaFX ProgressIndicator to show a new Stage()

Tags: java, javafx, task, nsprogressindicator

I have a method called enpointsList() which stage which contain a TableView. Now I have this ProgressIndicator which will run till this TableView shows up!

```
StackPane root = new StackPane();
            root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5)");
                    ProgressIndicator pi = new ProgressIndicator();
                    root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                    root.getChildren().add(pi);   
                    root.setMinWidth(700);
                    root.setMinHeight(500);
                    Scene c = new Scene(root, Color.TRANSPARENT);
                    Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>()
                    {
                        @Override
                        protected Void call() throws Exception
                        {
                            
                            request = specificVersion(URL);
                            endpointsList(request); //Create New Stage
                            Thread.sleep(150);
                            return null;
                        }
                    };
                    
                    pi.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());
                    task.setOnSucceeded((workerStateEvent) -> {
                        stage.close();
                        
                    });
                    new Thread(task).start();
                    
            stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
            stage.setX(350);
            stage.setY(100);
            stage.setScene(c);
            stage.setMinWidth(700);
            stage.setMinHeight(500);
            stage.show();
```

but always the progress indicator runs without end!

Comment: try to use Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){ //...

Comment: I tried it but it did not work

Comment: It's illegal to create a new stage on a background thread. If you use `task.setOnFailed()` you should see that an exception is getting thrown.

Comment: @James_D So there is no way to do it ?

Comment: You can't create a stage on a background thread, no. But there is never any reason to do so. Creating a stage doesn't take a significant amount of time.

Comment: Return your request. Then in `setOnSucceeded` do `endpointsList`.  That's assuming `endpointsList` is not a long task itself.

Comment: @Sedrick put this comment as an answer , it worked for me